# Help me solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m facing against some trouble when trying to solve a differential equation in my ODE assignment, say $$p^3-4txp+8x^2=0,$$here $p$ stands for $dx/dt$. Here’s what I’ve already got: consider it as a quadratic function with respect to variable $x$, and use the formula of finding the root, we get $$x=\frac{tp+\sqrt{t^2p^2-2p^3}}{4}\quad\text{or}\quad x=\frac{tp-\sqrt{t^2p^2-2p^3}}{4}.$$ I’m trying to derivative both sides with $dt$, yet to notice that the form is toooooo difficult to handle. I will be very appreciated if anyone can offer me some help!

Comment: A question to clarify, do you have the ODE:  $\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^{3}-4xt\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)+8x^{2} =0$, where $x=x(t)$?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s wrong with this ODE? Beg pardon, I didn’t quite catch your meaning

Comment: @Ramanujan The ODE in the question is the same as you wrote I think

Comment: See $x$ in my question acts the same as $y$ in your comment, and $t$ acts the same as $x$ here. You can re-write my question like $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3-4xy\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+8y^2=0$ if you want, it’s actually the same. Here $x,y$ are variables. @ZAhmed

Answer (score 2):

Here $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$, and we solve $$p^3-4xyp+8y^2=0 \implies x=\frac{p^2}{4y}+\frac{2y}{p}=0 ~~~(1)$$
Differentiating (1) w. r.t. $x$ and using $dy/dx=p$, simplifying we get
$$\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{p^2}{4y^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{2y}{p}\frac{dp}{dy}\right)=0~~~~(2)$$
First factor gives $$p^3=4y^2 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=(4y^2)^{1/3} \implies 27y=4x^3,~~~(3)$$
which is a singular solution with a constant of integration.
The other factor in (2) gives a family of curves
$$\frac{dp} {p}=\frac{dy}{2y}=0\implies p=C\sqrt{y} \implies \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=C dx \implies 4y=(Cx+D)^2~~~~(4)$$
**Edit:**

As suggested by @JJaquelin, if we put $(4)$ in (1), we get $C^3+4D=0$.
So the general solution of (1) becomes $$4y=(Cx-C^3/4)^2 \implies y=\frac{c^2}{4}\left(x-\frac{c^2}{4}\right)^2 \implies y=A(x-A)^2,$$ representing a familiy of parabolas and the singular /essential/solution is given by $27y=4x^3$ (3).

Comment: I don't understand why one can solve $$\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{p^2}{4y^2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{2y}{p}\frac{dp}{dy}\right)=0\quad (2)$$by simply letting two factors$\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{p^2}{4y^2}\right) , \left(1-\frac{2y}{p}\frac{dp}{dy}\right)$ equal to zero? There seems also no common solutions between two families of curves $27y=4x^3$ and $4y=(Cx+D)^2$

Comment: OH! I am sorry there was a typo in (2) it is a product not + sign. Sorry, I have corrected it now.

Comment: That would be all right! Appreciate it sooooooo much !!!!

Comment: @Z Ahmed. Did you check your result $4y=(Cx+D)^2$ in puting it into $(y')^3-4xy'y+8y^2=0$ ? I think it doesn't agree except if $C^3+4D=0$. In fact this is a particular solution on the form $y=A(x-A)^2$, but not the general solution.

Comment: Than you very much you have suggested a very good this. I am going to put it in my edit.  Thre needs to be only one constant and that is $A$ in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: $y=A(x-A)^2$ is a particular solution. This isn't the general solution.

Comment: Let us hope that someone will give the general solution as well.  But I  can see only two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer in parts of its steps suggests that $x=y^2$ might be a good substitution. Then
$$
(2yy')^3-4y^2t(2yy')+8y^4=0
$$
can, outside the solution $x(t)=0$, be reduced to
$$
y(t)=y'(t)t-y'(t)^3
$$
which is a Clairaut equation in standard form. One thus obtains the linear solution family
$$
y(t)=ct-c^3,~~\implies x(t)=c^2(t-c^2)^2,
$$
and the singular solution with $t=3y'^2$ which can be inserted into the DE to obtain
$$
y(t)=y'(t-y'^2)=\pm\frac2{3\sqrt3}t^{3/2},~~\implies x(t)=\frac4{27}t^3.
$$